# Lazy readonly property in Swift

Tags: swift

While playing a little bit with Swift I tried to write a readonly and lazy initialized property. I quickly wrote that line of code just to learn that it's not allowed.

```
// no valid Swift code.
lazy let foo : Int = { return 42 }()
```

You have to declare lazy properties as `var`.
The swift book clearly states that let with lazy is not possible for a good reason:

> “You must always declare a lazy property as a variable (with the var keyword), because its initial value might not be retrieved until after instance initialization completes. Constant properties must always have a value *before* initialization completes, and therefore cannot be declared as lazy.”

Supposing I would like to have a readonly lazy property in swift. What's the best way to archive that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If readonly and private are synonyms for you in this specific case, then you can make the setter private by explicitly declaring it:

```
private(set) lazy var foo : Int = { return 42 }()
```

That's a good compromise between immutability and laziness.

Comment: Private setter is sufficient for me. I often use that pattern in C#, too.

Comment: I think this is equivalent to ```private(set) lazy var foo = 42```. If you mark the setter as private there is no point in declaring the getter just for the purpose of omitting the setter.

Comment: It wasn't a getter, it is a lazy instantiation closure, but it is not necessary either since it does not contain any logic. That's why `private(set) lazy var foo = 42` will work just the same way.

Comment: This should work, but it doesn't: https://gist.github.com/4821ffb13e110dfeb027   Note: This is also a likely security issue.

Comment: @Barry: I presume that code is in the same file (or playground) - if yes, remember, that `private` doesn't make a property or method private to the class/struct, but private to the file, i.e. accessible from anywhere inside the file but unaccessible from anywhere

Comment: @Antonio: I think that has changed in recent Swift versions right? As we now have `fileprivate` and `private`.

Comment: @cumanzor that's right, `private` is to make it private to the type, `fileprivate` the same, but accessible from within the file where it is used.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use a private backing variable that initializes lazily:

```
var foo : Int { return _foo }
private lazy var _foo :Int = { return 42 }()
```

Comment: Although your answers is correct I prefer Antonios answer as it doesn't introduce another property.

Comment: Although the accepted answer doesn't currently work, this does.

Comment: @Barry the accepted answer works now (as of Xcode 7.1)

Answer (score 5):

Its possible to do this with a computed property and a private struct. There is no need for the lazy keyword on the static var value, as assigning it the result of a block is implicitly lazy.

```
var foo: Int {
    struct Holder {
        static var value = { return 42 }()
    }
    return Holder.value
}
```

Comment: This is clever, and useful in some case I think, but sadly, it is isn't useful when the computed value depends on the "self" object as swift doesn't allow inner structs to close over the outer scope.

Comment: @Daniel You make an excellent point, however this approach works perfectly in the context of the question.

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare the property at initialization time for it to be immutable.

```
class Class {
  let foo: Int
  init() {
    self.foo = 42
  }
}
```